# Is there any option in github to get the code from other user's repo?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I'm currently working on a development activity in my project (in a particular branch my seniors are already working for a part of that task) but, I'm not having much of knowledge on how to proceed with this activity, I need to refer my seniors code (I'm not going to perform any changes to the code, I just need read only access) and check to get some understanding. So, if I knew their username and branch name can I get the code changes they have made under that branch via gitbash? Is there any options for that?

Answer (score 1):

If the repository is public, anyone can browse the code. If the repository is private, then you must have access to that repo. If you have access to that repository I am sure you should be able to see all the branches and it's history through commits.

Answer (score 0):

[Fork Github Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXByG.jpg)You can FORK others repo.

You can see a button called "Fork" in the right-top corner. Click this and that will make a copy of that repository in your own github account.